# FD_SET causing seg fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, segmentation-fault, file-descriptor

I am running into an issue where `FD_SET` is crashing my program.  I am running the example code from a boost [Boost ASIO sample HTTP Server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3).  In the request handler, I put a third party api the eventually makes the following calls:

```
fd_set fds; 
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(sockfd, &fds);
```

My program seems to be crashing on the `FD_SET`. Is there a situation where calling `FD_SET` from different threads would cause a segfault? I am not sure exactly how `FD_SET` works, my gut feeling would be that I am calling `FD_SET` on a fd that is already in use.  Would this cause a problem at all?

`sockfd` is a class member, which is created each time a request comes in, so I should not be sharing a `sockfd` variable between threads.

Comment: What do you mean "seems like"? Can't you use a debugger to know for sure?

Comment: Have you checked that `sockfd` is positive, and less than `FD_SETSIZE`?

Comment: It does not crash every go through, and only crashes when my server is running around 1000 reqs/sec.  All I have is a backtrace, which does not give me the exact line.  When I have that code + code after that commented out, the program will run fine.  Once that line is in there, the program crashes.

Comment: I will look into the FD_SETSIZE problem, the code checks if the sockfd is < 0 though.

Comment: `FD_SET()` really just sets a bit in an array of unsigned integers. With the above code, the most likely reason for `FD_SET` failing or messing things up is that `sockfd` is out of range, e.g., because it is invalid or because the system parameter for available sockets is bigger than the bits available in `fd_set`.

Comment: The value of `sockfd` does grow to be greater than `FD_SETSIZE`. Eventually it does crash after that(not right away).

Comment: Is is possible to increase the size of available sockets on a linux system?  I have increased my fs.max-files on my system previously, but if there is another setting I could change, I would be all for doing it.

Comment: The problem is that increasing the number of available file descriptors on the system doesn't change the C library implementing these classes. Ideally, you'd change the code to us something different than the relatively inefficient `select()` to use `poll()` or `epoll()`. You problem is that the bits being set are somewhere in unrelated memory once the `FD_SETSIZE` is exceeded which is just a form of buffer overun.

Comment: @Eumcoz: You could use `poll` or `epoll`, or perhaps work at a higher level through the Boost library. I don't know whether there's any way to increase `FD_SETSIZE`, since I don't bother with `select` myself.

Comment: Sounds good guys, thank you for the info.  If you guys want to put up an answer, I'll gladly mark as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 1000 requests/second you are very likely eclipsing the `FD_SETSIZE` limit (typically 1024 on Linux), which results in [undefined behavior](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set):

> An **fd_set** is a fixed size buffer. Executing **FD_CLR()** or **FD_SET()** with
>   a value of fd that is negative or is equal to or larger than
>   **FD_SETSIZE** will result in undefined behavior. Moreover, POSIX requires
>   fd to be a valid file descriptor.

You should look at using [`poll`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), [`epoll`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll), or a higher level library like [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Any of those choices will not have the limitation of `select`.